# Converting XML with XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I am trying to convert xml to xsl. 
This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ml_root>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
        xml:base="http://ta-nb-manill.totalamber.com:7048/DynamicsNAV90/OData/"
        m:etag="W/&quot;'28%3BDgAAAAJ7%2F0IATABVAEUAAAAAAA%3D%3D6%3B1604150%3B'&quot;">
        <id>http://ta-nb-manill.totalamber.com:7048/DynamicsNAV90/OData/Company('CRONUS%20International%20Ltd.')/Location('BLUE')
        </id>
        <category term="NAV.Location"
            scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" title="Location"
            href="Company('CRONUS%20International%20Ltd.')/Location('BLUE')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2018-01-09T05:55:24Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Code>BLUE</d:Code>
                <d:Name>Blue Warehouse</d:Name>
                <d:ETag>28;DgAAAAJ7/0IATABVAEUAAAAAAA==6;1604150;</d:ETag>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</ml_root>
```

I tried to convert it using the following XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ROWS>
         <COMPANY_SITE_TAB>
            <xsl:for-each select="ml_root/entry/content/properties">
            <ROW>
               <COMPANY>TCO</COMPANY>
               <CONTRACT><xsl:value-of select="Code"/></CONTRACT>
               <COUNTRY>UNITED KINGDOM</COUNTRY>
               <DESCRIPTION><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></DESCRIPTION>
            </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </COMPANY_SITE_TAB>
      </ROWS>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it gives only the following output.

```
<ROWS>
   <COMPANY_SITE_TAB/>
</ROWS>
```

Can you please help me to understand the error.

Comment: XSL is a "language" in XML to specify a transformation taking input XML and converting it to some output.  You transform XML ***using*** XSL,  there aren't many use cases for transforming XML ***into*** XSL.  This would be like asking "I'm trying to convert my payroll data into a Java program".  Given the title, are you aware XSL and XSLT mean the same thing? Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?  What is the final output you want from the input XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the input XML carefully there are multiple namespaces (attributes starting with `xmlns`) associated with the elements in the XML. Since these namespaces are not mapped in the XSLT, the output XML does not show any data.

For the output XML, the elements from which data is being accessed belong to following namespaces

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
```

We need to map these namespaces in the XSLT as well and the namespaces are not required in the output, we use the `exclude-result-prefixes`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a d m">
```

The template needs to be modified to access elements according to the namespaces they belong to.

```
<xsl:for-each select="ml_root/a:entry/a:content/m:properties">
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="d:Code"/>
<xsl:value-of select="d:Name"/>
```

Below is the complete XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a d m">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ROWS>
         <COMPANY_SITE_TAB>
            <xsl:for-each select="ml_root/a:entry/a:content/m:properties">
            <ROW>
               <COMPANY>TCO</COMPANY>
               <CONTRACT><xsl:value-of select="d:Code"/></CONTRACT>
               <COUNTRY>UNITED KINGDOM</COUNTRY>
               <DESCRIPTION><xsl:value-of select="d:Name"/></DESCRIPTION>
            </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </COMPANY_SITE_TAB>
      </ROWS>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Following is the output.

```
<ROWS>
    <COMPANY_SITE_TAB>
        <ROW>
            <COMPANY>TCO</COMPANY>
            <CONTRACT>BLUE</CONTRACT>
            <COUNTRY>UNITED KINGDOM</COUNTRY>
            <DESCRIPTION>Blue Warehouse</DESCRIPTION>
        </ROW>
    </COMPANY_SITE_TAB>
</ROWS>
```

Comment: Please consider that I edited the xml file. But I still cannot get the required output.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per the updated input XML. There are different namespaces associated with `<m:properties>`, `<d:Code>` and `<d:Name>` which need to be mapped in XSLT.